# SignalR Method Calls - Faster than Conventional AJAX Calls?

Tags: ajax, signalr

If my web application has a number of regular AJAX methods in it, but I've introduced an always-on SignalR connection, is it worth refactoring to make the regular AJAX methods be hub methods instead?  Would it be faster since it's using the already-there connection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMHO this would be a misuse of SignalR.

Would it be faster? It really depends on several factors. The first of which is which transport ends up being used. If it's Web Sockets, then, yes, because a message will be sent over a connection that's guaranteed to already be established, but if it's SSE or LongPolling you're still doing a plain old HTTP POST every time to *send* messages. Second factor is that if the server is allowing Keep-Alive connections, then browsers will keep open TCP connections to the server for some period of time between requests anyway so there would be no overhead in terms of establishing a connection anyway.

Also, let's not forget our powerful friend the GET verb and all the goodness it brings in terms of one of the most important features of the web: caching.  If you have a lot of cacheable data, you wouldn't want to be sending real-time messages over web sockets to fetch and retrieve that because you're basically throw out the entire infrastructure of the web if you do. The browsers can't help you any more, you'd have to build all the intelligence yourself with local storage and custom messages which would be, for lack of a better word, insane. :) You also give up the power of proxies caching public data entirely as well which is extremely underrated in terms of how much it can help performance.

My guidance is that you leave what can be simple request/response exactly the way it is today leveraging AJAX and only use a technology like SignalR for what it's intended to be: real-time communications.

Comment: That's a fantastic and helpful reply, Drew.  Thank you so much!